# How to Overlay Text on Icons

Tags: nautilus, icons, text

I remember back in the day I used to have the opening snippet of txt files shown on my icons. I still have the icon set I used, which includes files like text-txt.icon

```
[Icon Data] 
EmbeddedTextRectangle=9,12,39,42
```

I have the same icon set, but something changed a while back and it doesn't display. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Tried using a different icon theme? I get that preview with some icon themes automatically but not with others. Never figured out what exactly enables it.

Comment: Ok, I found a theme that does it -- Faenza Radiance. I'll try to copy what it has going on.

Comment: If you find how and when it works, will be nice to post the answer here. I too struggled a bit to find it (and to find which thumbnailer does it) without success. Thanks!